# jQuery AJAX html(newhtml) outputs weird HTML

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have a jQuery AJAX function that gets new HTML from a PHP script. The PHP script works perfectly and sends back the correct HTML to jQuery, however, when I use the [html()](https://api.jquery.com/html/#html2) function, the outputted HTML is incorrect. I've put the HTML into a `<textarea>` to see if the returned code is correct, and it sure is. But when I try to output it into the HTML, it's like "corrupted".

Here's the jQuery function:

```
$(function() {
    $(".form-control").keyup(function() {
        var searchString = $(this).val();
        var dataString = 'search=' + searchString;
        if(searchString != '') {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "core/handle.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache:false,
                success: function(html) {
                    var start = '<div class="row"><h2>' + searchString + '</h2>';
                    var end = '</div>';
                    html = start + html + end;
                    $("#books-wrapper").html(html);
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Here's the output when using jQuery's html() function into a `<textarea>`:

```
<div class="col-lg-3>
    <a href="index.php?id=1" class="thumbnail">
        <img src="img/books/book_1.jpg" alt="Book one">
    </a>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-3>
    <a href="index.php?id=2" class="thumbnail">
        <img src="img/books/book_2.jpg" alt="Book two">
    </a>
</div>
```

And here's the actual source-code output:

```
<div id="books-wrapper">
    <div class="row">
        <h2>b</h2>
           <div class="col-lg-3>
                <a href=" index.php?id="1&quot;">
                <img src="img/books/book_1.jpg" alt="Book one">
           </div>
           <div class="col-lg-3>
                <a href=" index.php?id="2&quot;">
                <img src="img/books/book_2.jpg" alt="Book two">
           </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the closing quote in class="col-lg-3^^^, check for similar mistake also close anchor tag with `</a>`

*Change*

```
<div class="col-lg-3>
```

*To*

```
<div class="col-lg-3">
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, that you should do `html = start + html.prop('outerHTML') + end`
Because "html" (variable) is a DOM object of jQuery, and not a string.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href=" index.php?id="1&quot;">
```

should be

```
<a href=' index.php?id="1&quot;"'>
```